# Not following symbolic link after changing remote server PHP

Tags: apache, svn, virtualhost, symlink

After changing remote servers (but not the content being hosted in it), my symbolic links are no longer being followed by apache through virtual hosts.

When I go into the terminal and perform ls -alt it shows that the symlink is there and correct.

The path where the symlink is going to (and suppose to be going to is correct) and the content expected is still there.

I have performed svn switch on the root of the content that the symlink is going to so its updated to the current server.

I have checked and opened up all file permissions for the content and subdirectories

I have tried svn switch on the content that s symlinking to the shared content, but am presented with this error:
'.' appears to be part of version 1.7, please upgrade your client version.

I deleted the folder with symlink and re-checked it out through the new server, this is where the symlink doesnt work anymore.

Some of my older projects that were checked out through the old server do follow the symlink to the content with the svn re-directed to the new server.

**Also my virtual host which states the option to follow symlinks has multiple places where the same symlink path is used. Each folder inside this vhost has the same substructure to it, but oddly some symlinks work, and others dont.**

Any ideas on what I could try to get apache to follow the sym links?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you checked your virtualhost directory block configuration? (There's a specific `Options FollowSymLinks` option.)

Comment: already set, should have noted that one

Comment: For the links that are working I am getting good svn info, while the ones that dont work I am getting this error: svn: The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater. The new server is 1.6.11. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following symlinks is OFF by default on most Apache installs, because they're a security risk - they allow easy violation of document root "jails". if you allow symlinks, it's trivial to have something like `ln -s / /site/documentroot/browse` and now your entire filesystem is open for viewing by the world.

If you insist on allowing them, then you'll need

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

in the appropriate `<directory>`, `<virtualhost>` or `.htaccess1`. Relevant docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Comment: sorry, should have noted that, My virtual host httpd-vhosts file does have the Options +FollowSymlinks in there already